# What does IO do?

Tags: ruby

What does the (0, IO::SEEK_SET) do in method rewind? I understand the rest of the code, but I am honestly stuck at the (0, IO::SEEK_SET).

```
input_file = ARGV[0]

def print_all(f)
  puts f.read()
end

def rewind(f)
  f.seek(0, IO::SEEK_SET)
end

def print_a_line(line_count, f)
  puts "#{line_count} #{f.readline()}"
end

current_file = File.open(input_file)

puts "First let's print the whole file:"
puts # a blank line

print_all(current_file)

puts "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

puts "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Answer (score 3):

**seek(amount, whence=IO::SEEK_SET) → 0**
Seeks to a given offset *amount* in the stream according to the value of *whence*:

```
:CUR or IO::SEEK_CUR  | Seeks to _amount_ plus current position
----------------------+--------------------------------------------------
:END or IO::SEEK_END  | Seeks to _amount_ plus end of stream (you
                      | probably want a negative value for _amount_)
----------------------+--------------------------------------------------
:SET or IO::SEEK_SET  | Seeks to the absolute location given by _amount_
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-seek

Comment: What does "Seeks to the absolute location given by _amount_" exactly mean? Does it mean look for the original file location?

Comment: Generally, when documentation refers to an "absolute offset" in a file, they mean "starting from the beginning of the file."  So "amount," in this case, refers to the position corresponding to the beginning of the file (usually zero) + amount.  In other words, "amount" means "absolute position."

Comment: So the (0, IO::SEEK_SET) starts from the specific location within the file due to the '0' in (0, IO::SEEK_SET). If I were to change the number to, let say, '3' then would that begin from a different location from the same file?

Comment: If you use Seek with a setting of IO::SEEK_SET and an amount of 3, then your position will be set to 3.  If you use Seek with a setting of IO::SEEK_SET and an amount of 256, then your position will be set to 256.  This is true regardless of the current position of the file.

Comment: I believe I'm starting to get this. Lets say we started the amount at 5, so the position will be set to 5; does this mean that it will start at line 5 of the code?

Comment: It means that, when you next read from the file, it will begin reading at byte position 5 in the file.

Comment: When you say "byte" are you talking about storage (like MB, KB, etc?) or is it a different kind of byte? So, if I had 1024 spaces, letters, punctuation mark, symbols, and etc.; does that mean each of those individual markings (or non-markings with the space) are worth 1 byte of memory?

Comment: Why don't you try running a few experiments?

Answer (score 2):

When you specify a position to seek to, there are typically three ways to do this

```
SEEK_SET: from the start of the file (ie: absolute)
SEEK_CUR: from the current position (ie: relative)
SEEK_END: from the end of the file
```

So in your case the rewind method simply seeks to the beginning of the file.